# What tenses are used in the sentence "He needn't have been anxious though"?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, sentence-structure

I have found this sentence in a text book so I suppose it's correct, but I'm a bit confused. I thought that when the verb "need" is used as a modal verb it must be followed by a verb in base form.

Comment: The immediate complement of *need* here is *have*, which **is** in base form. Then *have* takes the complement *been*, a past participle because this is a perfect construction: not a present perfect but an infinitive perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Past tense

*Need not* by itself is a present tense action, though when *have been* is added to the end, we are assuming he **was previously** not needing. i.e. he did not need ____ in the past.

In this example,

> *[In the past]* he did not need to be anxious.

or more like the example

> He need not to *have been* anxious [in the past], though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is Present Perfect Continuous, since the phrase is in the present but references the past.